# Create array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

```
   myArray = [
    {
      obj: {
        name: "Andy",
        phone: ["11111111", "22222222"],
        email: ["andy@andy.com"],
      },
    },
    {obj: { name: "Kate", phone: ["073463653"] } },
    {obj: { name: "July", email: ["july@gmail.com", "july@bes.com"] } },
  ];
```

I've tried something like this, but I can't map through the phone no and get a valid result. If you guys have an idea or some suggestions I would really appreciate it

```
  ngOnInit() {
    Object.keys(
      this.myArray.map((key) => {
        const objectWithData = {
          [name]: key._objectReference.name,
          phoneNumbers: key._objectReference.phoneNumbers.map((each) => {
            phoneNumbers: each;
          }),
        };
        return objectWithData;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: you have to return the objectWithEachData, otherwise it returns an array of "undefined"

Comment: where is "Kate" ?

Comment: i am sorry, just saw that and I've included

Comment: @raz I've tried but still doesn't work, I think the undefined comes from when I try to map the array of phone no, but not sure how else I can take each no

Comment: The last item in the array doesn't have a phone number, also the "[name]" should be "name". You can check if the phone number exists with `phoneNumbers: key._objectReference.phoneNumbers?.map(each => each)` . Also, you can remove Object.keys(...)

Comment: is it really necessary to have an array of only one element for phone Number and email(s?

Comment: Yes, i need to have a big array and in that one an object for each person and with only one eg: phone number, another object for the same person with the other phone no and for email I need the same so at first I have an object for one person and I want to have two with each for no   {
    name: "Andy",
    phoneNumber: ["111111111"],
    emails: ["andy@andy.com"],
  }, 
  {
    name: "Andy",
    phoneNumber: ["22222222"],
    emails: ["andy@andy.com"],
  },

Comment: you need to get  only one of each phoneNumber or email, is it really necessary to have an array of only one element for phoneNumber and email(s) in the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, I'd prefer to use reduce for something like this with the phone numbers/emails and find it more readable than the nested mapping. Also, I would change the resulting model to strings instead of arrays since you are showing a different model anyway that isn't really lists. You can modify the below to put them in arrays if you need to...

Also, you'll notice the keys are still there for undefined properties. If you want to leave the keys out you'd just have to build up the object conditionally before passing to `newArr.push({})`;

EDIT:

After reviewing the OP I see now that you meant for names to be repeated in the results for each phone/email - and repeating the first element in the shorter array if possible (e.g., andy's one email repeating for each phone number).

The below is the best I can do for this, it works, just does not look all that elegant IMO.

The assumption is that in the case you have more phone numbers than emails or vice versa, you want to repeat the first element of the shorter array in order to always include that contact option in each contact record. Otherwise each contact record would have a phone number and email with matching indexes in the respective arrays.

I first check to determine which array is longer (phone or email) and loop only once through the longer one so you get every contact option in the loop and create contact records in the new array for each element in the longer array.

For the phone and email fields, each ugly expression determines:
-Are there any phone/email options?
-Are there options at the current index (of the longer array loop)?
-If not, is there an element in the first position to use as default?
-Else leave it undefined

```js
function mapContacts(arr) {
  var longerArr;
  
  return arr.reduce((newArr, currEle) => {
  
    currEle = currEle.obj;
    
    if (currEle.phone && currEle.phone.length > (currEle.email ? currEle.email.length : 0)) {
      longerArr = currEle.phone;
    } else if (currEle.email && currEle.email.length > 0) {
      longerArr = currEle.email;
    } else {
      return; // No contact info
    }
    
    longerArr.forEach((ele, index) => {
      newArr.push({
        name: currEle.name,
        phone: currEle.phone && (currEle.phone[index] ? currEle.phone[index] : 
          (currEle.phone[0] && currEle.phone[0])),
        email: currEle.email && (currEle.email[index] ? currEle.email[index] : 
          (currEle.email[0] && currEle.email[0]))
      });
    });
    
    return newArr;
  }, []);
}

var myArray = [
    {
      obj: {
        name: "Andy",
        phone: ["11111111", "22222222"],
        email: ["andy@andy.com"]
      }
    },
    { obj: { name: "Kate", phone: ["073463653"] } },
    { obj: { name: "July", email: ["july@gmail.com", "july@bes.com"] } },
    { obj: { name: "Jay", phone: ["489375438"], email: ["jay@gmail.com", "jay@bes.com"] } },
];

var newArr = mapContacts(myArray);

console.log(newArr);

/* Output
[
  {
    "name": "Andy",
    "phone": "11111111",
    "email": "andy@andy.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Andy",
    "phone": "22222222",
    "email": "andy@andy.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kate",
    "phone": "073463653",
    "email": undefined
  },
  {
    "name": "July",
    "phone": undefined,
    "email": "july@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "July",
    "phone": undefined,
    "email": "july@bes.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jay",
    "phone": "489375438",
    "email": "jay@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jay",
    "phone": "489375438",
    "email": "jay@bes.com"
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I just noticed now that the second no for andy is not displayed in an object. DO you have any idea how we can do it?

Comment: @alex what do you mean exactly by "second no" and "displayed in an object"? If you're referring to the second phone number I thought your OP said you wanted just one phone number so I assumed the first...

Comment: I just went back to your OP and I see what you're saying now, didn't realize you're adding multiple contacts to the new array for each phone number/email. I can edit my post to do that with a few assumptions...

Comment: @alex just reposted with new solution

Answer (score 1):

Does it fit an answer for you ?

first answer

```js
const myArray = 
      [ { _objectReference: 
          { name:         "Andy"
          , phoneNumbers: [ "11111111", "22222222"] 
          , emails:       [ "andy@andy.com"] 
          } 
        } 
      , { _objectReference: 
          { name:         "Kate"
          , phoneNumbers: [ "073463653"] 
          } 
        } 
      , { _objectReference: 
          { name:    "July"
          , emails: [ "july@gmail.com", "july@bes.com"] 
          } 
        } 
      ] 

const newArrayContacts = 
  myArray.reduce((a,c)=>
    {
    let row  = c._objectReference
     , newEl = { name: row.name }

    if (row.phoneNumbers) { newEl.phoneNumber = row.phoneNumbers[0] }
    if (row.emails)       { newEl.email       = row.emails[0] }
  
    if ( row.phoneNumbers
      && row.phoneNumbers.length > 1 )
      {
      row.phoneNumbers.forEach(phoneNumber =>
        {  
        newEl.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        a.push ( {...newEl } )
        })
      }
    else if (row.emails 
          && row.emails.length > 1 ) 
      {
      row.emails.forEach(email =>
        {
        newEl.email = email
        a.push ( {...newEl } )
        })
      }
    else  
      { a.push ( newEl ) }

    return a
    },[])

console.log( newArrayContacts )
```

second answer (Angular ?)

```js
const myArray = 
  [ { name: "Andy", phoneNumbers: [ "11111111", "22222222"] , emails: [ "andy@andy.com"] } 
  , { name: "Kate", phoneNumbers: [ "073463653"] } 
  , { name: "July", emails: [ "july@gmail.com", "july@bes.com"] } 
  ] 

const newArrayContacts = 
  myArray.reduce((acc,row)=>
    {
    let newEl = { name: row.name }

    if (row.phoneNumbers) { newEl.phoneNumber = [row.phoneNumbers[0]] }
    if (row.emails)       { newEl.email       = [row.emails[0]]  }

    if ( row.phoneNumbers
      && row.phoneNumbers.length > 1 )
      {
      row.phoneNumbers.forEach((phoneNumber)=>
        {  
        newEl.phoneNumber = [phoneNumber]
        acc.push ( {...newEl } )
        })
      }
    else if (row.emails 
          && row.emails.length > 1 ) 
      {
      row.emails.forEach(email =>
        {
        newEl.email = [email]
        acc.push ( {...newEl } )
        })
      }
    else  
      { acc.push ( newEl ) }

    return acc
    },[])

console.log( JSON.stringify( newArrayContacts,0,2) )
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply!Not sure why I get Property 'phoneNumber' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }' and same for email Property 'email' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'. What do you think?

Comment: @Alexandra this is unclear, which result do you expect ?

Comment: as you wrote it's exactly the outcome I am looking for but when I add your code into my visual studio code here. "  newEl.phoneNumber = c._objectReference.phoneNumbers[0];" it says "Property 'phoneNumber' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'."

Comment: I think that's because it's Angular, but not sure how to sort this. I've tried to declare along phoneNo and email along with name in here  let newEl = { name: c._objectReference.name }; but no success

Comment: @Alexandra  sorry i hadn't seen this was an angular question. I think _objectReference is useless to test this code

Comment: @Alexandra  I added a second answer, I let you test it for angular... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219880/discussion-between-alexandra-and-mister-jojo).

Answer (score -1):

the map function returns nothing

```
  phoneNumbers: key._objectReference.phoneNumbers.map((each) => {
    phoneNumbers: each;
  }),
```

you have to return the object

```
  phoneNumbers: key._objectReference.phoneNumbers.map((each) => return {
    phoneNumbers: each
  }),
```

or

```
phoneNumbers: key._objectReference.phoneNumbers.map((each) => ({
  phoneNumbers: each
})),
```

but that doesn't solve your overall problem.

to solve this i don't think you can use only the map function as it returns an array with the same number of elements as the original,
i would use nested for / foreach and build an array as i go

Comment: When I console.log each it doesn't return an array, but each phone number available